# How to pass data via header or query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Using SignalR in .NET 4.7 we were able to pass two variables from the client application to SignalR server. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    protected (string myVar1, string myVar2) GetValues() =>
            (
            Context.QueryString["MyVariable1"] ?? string.Empty,
            Context.QueryString["MyVariable2"] ?? string.Empty,
            );
}
```

The javascript client would set these variables as follows:

```
$.connection.hub.qs = {'MyVariable1' : 'val1', 'MyVariable2' : 'val2'};
```

Now, we are trying to migrate to the alpha release of SignalR for .NET Core 2.0 applications. The blocker is that we can no longer use this method to obtain myVar1 and myVar2 values. Not only `QueryString` is unavailable but also headers. What is the best way to overcome this situation to be able to pass variables from client app (Typescript) or even .net core app to SignalR  server side?

Also - how do you set variables on client side?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can access the `HttpContext` in your hub like this:

```
var httpContext = Context.Connection.GetHttpContext();
```

and then use `httpContext.Request.Query["MyVariable"]` to get the variable value

**Edit for ASPNetCore 2.1 and later**

`GetHttpContext()` extension method is directly accessible on `Context` object

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
....
var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
```

Comment: Note to others: this is an extension method so you won't see it listed until you include the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR namespace.

Comment: Hi, could u give some example to insert the parameter in connection with c#?
I'm using HubConnectionBuilder to create and start my connection.

Comment: Just append the parameter to the query string you pass to start the connection?

Comment: I still cannot see the extension method with reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR? in .net core 2.1?

Comment: You are likely missing a using statement. You can find this extension method [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/2d4fb0af6fd2ef2e3a059a2a15a56484d8800d35/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections/HttpConnectionContextExtensions.cs#L12).

Answer (score 8):

Late joining in this thread. The only way I could get this mechanism to work in .net core 2.2 was by:

#1 Adding two Nuget packages

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

#2 Then in our methods pe OnConnectedAsync():

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new Exception("...");

        var query = httpContext.Request.Query;
        var userId = query.GetQueryParameterValue<long>("Foo");
        var clientId = query.GetQueryParameterValue<string>("Bar");
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        [...]

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

#3 Also introduced some handy SignalR extensions:

```
    static public class SignalrExtensions
    {
       static public HttpContext GetHttpContext(this HubCallerContext context) =>
          context
            ?.Features
            .Select(x => x.Value as IHttpContextFeature)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x != null)
            ?.HttpContext;

       static public T GetQueryParameterValue<T>(this IQueryCollection httpQuery, string queryParameterName) =>
          httpQuery.TryGetValue(queryParameterName, out var value) && value.Any()
            ? (T) Convert.ChangeType(value.FirstOrDefault(), typeof(T))
            : default;
    }
```

Hope this helps.